# ClassNotFoundException while deploying ear in wildfly8.1

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly, ejb-2.x, wildfly-8

I am moving my jboss 4 application to wildfly

It consist of 10 modules
i have added it in appliction.xml
i have also added this entry true

i copied my all my thirdparty jars into ear/lib folder
i have updated all my ejb-jar.xml DTDs

my ejb modules are 2.0

but while deploying i am getting these error

```
caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.firstapex.fic.cps.services.vo.CPSDetailVo from [Module "deployment.FirstGen20140802_121633.ear.ficquot.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
  ... 14 more
```

server version : wildfly 8.1 final
os: windows xp
jdk:1.7

Comment: Can you post the structure of your ear?

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/thread/243528   last comment :)